# How can I activate extensions in Banshee 2.9 (really 2.6.2)?

Tags: banshee, extension, lyrics

- I have updated to Ubuntu 14.04
- I have updated Banshee to 2.9+really2.6.2.

I can see there's no more extensions available.

- How can I install all the extensions from the earlier versions(2.4)?

```
Im looking for the lyrics, kareoke and album cover extensions.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer an alternative for the Lyrics extension.

First check this [Can not Install `banshee-extension-lyrics`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462390/can-not-install-banshee-extension-lyrics), that explains it still (to the date) doesnt work on 14.04. Still there there is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/469903/46437) that lets you keep using banshee!